# unable to skip preflight options when using get and authorization

Tags: angularjs, rest, typescript, httpclient, preflight

If I leave out Authorization in header, GET api is called. If I add authorization, OPTIONS is called. How can use Authorization and use GET instead of OPTIONS?

```
const headers = new HttpHeaders({
    'Content-Type': 'text/plain',
    Authorization: 'Bearer ' + token,
  });

const newReq = req.clone({headers});
```

Comment: You can’t. _Because_ you are adding this header, a pre-flight request is required - and that is made using the OPTIONS method. If the response to that indicates that your cross-domain request is allowed, then your browser will make the original GET request afterwards. Go read up on how CORS works ...

Comment: use a server side proxy to make the request when endpoint isn't cors enabled